# Selecting Postgres UUID's on Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel, uuid

I have a table on Postgres that auto generates UUIDs, when I dd `Customer::all();` on Laravel I get an array with `"cs_id" => "d0402be5-e1ba-4cb2-a80c-5340b406e2c3"` which is fine. When I loop or select one record with the only the cs_id the data it retuns 0,2,5 for the three records currently on the table which is incorrect data.

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
  cs_id character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
CONSTRAINT cs_customers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (cs_id),
}
```

On laravel

```
$customerData = Customer::where('cs_id','d0402be5-e1ba-4cb2-a80c-5340b406e2c3')->first();

dd($customerData['cs_id']);
```

Comment: please provide code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason Eloquent messes up there.

just add a getter and use it whenever you need the cs_id

```
public function getGuid()
{
    return $this->attributes['cs_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use uuids auto-generated by the database, define your model as follows:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    // rename the id column (optional)
    protected $primaryKey = 'cs_id';

    // tell Eloquent that your id is not an integer
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    // do NOT set $incrementing to false
}
```

Then you can use all Eloquent's methods as you would with classic ids:

```
$customerData = Customer::findOrFail('d0402be5-e1ba-4cb2-a80c-5340b406e2c3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Customer::findOrFail('d0402be5-e1ba-4cb2-a80c-5340b406e2c3');`

to get the record matching that pk.

I'm assuming on top you have `use App\Customer;`